# Is it possible to add a Target to a .xcworkspace via the command line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, command-line

I have a scenario where I need one .xcworkspace file and several targets inside of it for up to 1000 different applications (all using the same codebase, just with different Bundle IDs, new icon files, and a couple info.plist additions). What I'd like to do is script this instead of clicking Add Target, and going through that process one thousand different times. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to think about my problem that doesn't involve targets?

Comment: It's not really pertinent to the question, but can I just ask *why* you're building so many different targets from a single codebase, out of interest?

Comment: One singular codebase for franchised merchants of one product. Each merchant wants their colors, their logos, and their own App on the App Store.

Comment: Did you find any solution?